# How to find the depth of a binary tree using Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am learning Prolog and am trying to find the depth of a **binary tree** using Prolog.
I represent a tree like this:

```
nil is a tree.
tree(1,nil,nil) this is a leaf.
tree(1,tree(1,nil,nil),nil) this is a tree with root 1 and has a left leaf 1.
```

I want a depth predicate that depth(T, N) that will be true if N is the depth of the tree T. 
I assume that I'll use the depth predicate when T isn't a variable but N can be a variable. 
**Examples:**

```
?- depth(nil,N).
N = 0.

?- depth(tree(1,tree(2,nil,tree(3,nil,nil)),tree(5,tree(6,nil,nil),nil)),N).
N = 3.

?- depth(tree(1,nil,tree(2,nil,nil)),N).
N = 2.
```

I am not sure how do that N will be the maximum between the 2 subtrees.

Thanks for any help.

Solution:

```
depth(nil,0).
depth(tree(_,nil,nil),1).
depth(tree(_,Left,Right), D) :- 
    depth(Left,DLeft),
    depth(Right,DRight),
    D is max(DLeft, DRight) + 1.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy as pie: the depth of `nil` is 0:

```
depth(nil,0).
```

For the `tree` case, recursively call `depth/2` on both branches and `max` them:

```
depth(Left,DLeft),
depth(Right,DRight),
D is max(DLeft, DRight) + 1.
```

Comment: I get the next ERROR: "ERROR: =</2: Arithmetic: `depth/1' is not a function". EDITED ABOVE.

Comment: Let me guess, you're probably calling `max(depth(L), depth(R))`? That won't work. Call `depth` twice to get the values, then `max` them in the next line.

Comment: You can't use a user-defined predicate in `is/2`, at least not with extra (non-portable) code. Just call the predicate twice.

Comment: Many thanks it works now. I am new to Prolog so the next questions will prolly sound stupid but: 1)Why I can't use user-defined predicate? 2)max is a build-in function/predicate? 3)When you say is/2 what does it mean, I believe it will help me to understand the errors better.

Comment: 1) You just can't. Some Prologs allow it, but ISO Standard Prolog doesn't, IIRC. 2) Yes. 3) `is/2` is the `is` infix predicate for arithmetic evaluation. It takes two arguments (its left and right hand side), hence `/2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
% I added Root \= nil, simulating a null node and it works

depth_tree(nil, 0).

depth_tree(node(Root, Left, Right), Depth):- 

      Root\= nil, 

      depth_tree(Left, DepthLeft),

      depth_tree(Right, DepthRight),

      Depth is max(DepthLeft, DepthRight) + 1.
```