# Prolog: How to calculate depth of tree with an arbitrary amount of subtrees?

Tags: prolog

I represent trees with an arbitrary, but finite, amount of subtrees like this:

```
tree(empty).
tree(branch(R, Ts)) :- integer(R), isTreeList(Ts).

isTreeList([]).
isTreeList([T | Ts]) :- tree(T), isTreeList(Ts).
```

(please ignore if this representation is good or bad, it's just for the purpose of asking this question)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767868/how-to-find-the-depth-of-a-binary-tree-using-prolog) post shows how calculate the depth of a binary tree. My progress so far:

```
depth(tree(empty), 0).
depth(tree(branch(_, SubTrees), D) 
    :- < calculate somehow the depths D1, ..., Dn of the subtrees >
    ,  max_list([D1, ..., Dn], MaxD)
    ,  D is MaxD + 1
```

How do I determine `D1, ..., Dn`?

EDIT: According to @CapelliC the following is one solution to the problem:

```
depth(tree(empty), 0).
depth(tree(branch(_, SubTrees), D) 
    :- maplist(depth, SubTrees, Depths)
    ,  max_list(Depths, MaxD)
    ,  D is MaxD + 1
```

Mind that this will fail if `SubTrees` is the empty list – the solution of @max66 will still work.

Comment: just `maplist(depth, SubTrees, Depths)`

Comment: @CapelliC So the right hand side would look like `:- maplist(depth, SubTrees, Depths), max_list(depths, MaxD), D is MaxD + 1.` ?

Comment: `max_list(Depths, MaxD)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the max value everytime you calculate a value in the list.

I mean

```
depth(tree(empty), 0).
depth([], 0).
depth([T | L], D) :-
  depth(T, D0),
  depth(L, D1),
  D is max(D0, D1).
depth(tree(branch(_, SubTrees)), D) :-
  depth(SubTrees, D0),
  D is D0+1.
```